# JavaScript Date.UTC giving wrong date in different time zone

Tags: javascript

i'm using javascript `Date.UTC` as below,

`var dt = new Date(Date.UTC(2014,09,17))`

it's giving me result as `"Thu Oct 16 17:00:00 PDT 2014"` if i change my local time zone to 
UTC -08:00 Pacific Time..

what could be the reason that its giving date 1 day of from actual date?

Note: results are varying according to browser. in FF its giving `"NaN undefined NaN"` and in IE, Chrome its giving `"Thu Oct 16 17:00:00 PDT 2014"`

Comment: Your time zone is 8 hours behind UTC. So when it's 9/17 in UTC, it's still 9/16 in your time zone.

Comment: BTW, months are zero-based. That should be giving you a date in October, not September.

Comment: Oct 16 is Tuesday, not Thursday. You're obviously not pasting the actual results, why not?

Comment: @Barmar: so how can i get the actual date rather than according to time zone on local machine

Comment: If not the local time zone, what time zone should it be in?

Comment: @Rohaan—if you want UTC, then do `dt.toISOString()` (see [*Date.prototype.toISOString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.43)) or use the UTC methods to get UTC time values.

Comment: @Barmar: it should be the actual value as it is

Comment: You don't understand how dates work. When it's 9/16 20:00 in California, it's 9/17 04:00 in London. Those are both the same Date object. Which one of those is the "actual value"?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript Date objects use a UTC time value at their heart. By default, they will return local values for dates and times.

To access the UTC values, use UTC methods like [*getUTCFullYear*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.11), [*getUTCHours*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.19), etc. or perhaps just use [*Date.prototype.toISOString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.43), which returns an ISO 8601 format date in UTC timezone, or use [*Date.prototype.toUTCString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.42) which returns an implementation dependant string in UTC timezone:

```
var dt = new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 8, 17))

console.log(dt.toISOString()); // 2014-09-17T00:00:00.000Z
console.log(dt.toUTCString()); // Wed, 17 Sep 2014 00:00:00 GMT
```

Note that you should not use Numbers like `08` as that may be interpreted by some individuals as an octal number, not decimal.